# How to send a tweet to a radio show

Tags: twitter

I am trying to tweet poems to NPR's "Tell Me More."  When I tweet in the "what's happening?" box on my homepage w/ TMM's address in my address bar or in the search box, they appear on my homepage.

I know a DM won't work because Michel Martin probably isn't following me!  Would an @user work in this case?  If not, what is the proper way to send a tweet to a radio show? Should I expect some sort of acknowledgment of their receipt of my tweet?

Answer (score 2):

I would assume you would you use the hashtag #tmmpoetry and/or mention the user (@TellMeMoreNPR) directly.

It does not seem they give acknowledgement except for those they select,

> *we like your poetic tweet. Please email me at [...] to learn more about next steps!*